# React : is there a way to console.log all props passed down to a stateless component?

Tags: reactjs

For a class component, one would console.log "this.props" and get all the props. What would be the equivalent for a stateless/functional component?

For example, in the following component, how can one see all props quickly ? (particularly those offered by withRouter)

```
const CollaboratorListContainer = ({
  searchTerm,
  handleFilterChange,
  visibleFilters,
  setVisibleFilters,
  deleteCollaborators,
  companyId,
  title,
}) => {
  return(
    <Grid fluid>
      <MainContentHeader
         title={'Collaborateurs'}
      />
      <div className="main-content">
        <Card>
          <ListFilterForm
            onFilterChange={handleFilterChange}
            values={{ searchTerm }}
            visible={visibleFilters} text  />
        <CollaboratorList
            deleteCollaborators={deleteCollaborators}
            onRowSelect={(inSelection) => setVisibleFilters(!inSelection)}
            companyId={companyId}
            searchTerm={searchTerm} />
        </Card>
      </div>
    </Grid>
 )
}


export default compose(
  withRouter,
  searchTerm,
  visibleFilters,
  handlers,
  pure
)(CollaboratorListContainer);
```

Comment: just console log `props`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `stateless functional` components, the `props` can be obtained from the function `argument` like

```
const MyComp = (props) => {
   return <div>Hello {props.name}</div>
}
```

In case you want to see specific props, you can destructure it separately but there is not no way of knowing the props added by a specific HOC

```
const CollaboratorListContainer = ({
  match,
  location,
  history,
  searchTerm,
  handleFilterChange,
  visibleFilters,
  setVisibleFilters,
  deleteCollaborators,
  companyId,
  title,
}) => {
  console.log(match, location, history);
  return(
    <Grid fluid>
      <MainContentHeader
         title={'Collaborateurs'}
      />
      <div className="main-content">
        <Card>
          <ListFilterForm
            onFilterChange={handleFilterChange}
            values={{ searchTerm }}
            visible={visibleFilters} text  />
        <CollaboratorList
            deleteCollaborators={deleteCollaborators}
            onRowSelect={(inSelection) => setVisibleFilters(!inSelection)}
            companyId={companyId}
            searchTerm={searchTerm} />
        </Card>
      </div>
    </Grid>
 )
}
```

Comment: thanks Shubham Khatri... I edited the question to be more specific. When using hoc like withRouter, is there a way to console.log the props added by this one ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve that using **recompose.lifecycle()**:

https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#lifecycle

- Also: https://medium.com/@leathcooper/using-recompose-to-make-stateless-functional-components-work-well-with-react-router-4-x-47988e20ee31

Yes it works, I've tested now doing this:

```js
import { compose, lifecycle } from 'recompose';

const log = lifecycle({
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('all props', this.props);
  },
});

export default compose(
  injectIntl,
  withRouter,
  log,
)(Container);
```

Comment: what do you think the output of this.props will be in your case. Will it be only withRouter props or only injectIntl props. According to me it will contains all the props from both the HOCs but what if you wish to only check the props added by a specific HOC

Comment: Even if you write `export default compose(
  injectIntl,
  log,
  withRouter,
  log,
)(Container);` the output will definitely be separated out, but still the individual HOCs props won't be available

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri although the question here is: "is there a way to console.log ALL PROPS passed down to a stateless component?", you have a good point, I can't think of a way of logging only the props added by a specific HOC.